# group elements by rel attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using equalHeightColumns.js to provide a cross browser equal height, which works fine until I need to have 2 sets of equal height.

So at the moment I have:

```
$(".row").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".equalHeight").equalHeightColumns();
});

<div class="row">
     <section class="equalHeight"></section>
     <section class="equalHeight"></section>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <section class="equalHeight"></section>
     <section class="equalHeight"></section>
</div>
```

As you can see I dont want everything with the equalHeight to have the same height only inside the same row.

The problem is that now I need to change the mark up and dont have the row to reference. Is it possible to make this work like the lightbox `rel='group2'` plugin so that I can group the equalHeight elements via attribute.

E.g: this would be

```
<section class="equalHeight" rel="group1"></section>
<section class="equalHeight" rel="group1"></section>

<section class="equalHeight" rel="group2"></section>
<section class="equalHeight" rel="group2"></section>
```

equalHeightColumns.js

```
/*!
* equalHeightColumns.js 1.0
*
* Copyright 2013, Paul Sprangers http://paulsprangers.com
* Released under the WTFPL license
* http://www.wtfpl.net
*
* Date: Thu Feb 21 20:11:00 2013 +0100
*/
(function($) {
    $.fn.equalHeightColumns = function(options) {
        defaults = {
            minWidth: -1,               // Won't resize unless window is wider than this value
            maxWidth: 99999,            // Won't resize unless window is narrower than this value
            setHeightOn: 'min-height',  // The CSS attribute on which the equal height is set. Usually height or min-height
            heightMethod: 'outerHeight',// Height calculation method: height, innerHeight or outerHeight
            delay: false,
            delayCount: 100
        };
        var $this   = $(this); // store the object
        options     = $.extend({}, defaults, options); // merge options

        // Recalculate the distance to the top of the element to keep it centered
        var resizeHeight = function(){

            // Get window width
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();

            // Check to see if the current browser width falls within the set minWidth and maxWidth
            if(options.minWidth < windowWidth  &&  options.maxWidth > windowWidth){
                var height = 0;
                var highest = 0;

                // Reset heights
                $this.css( options.setHeightOn, 0 );

                // Figure out the highest element
                $this.each( function(){
                    height = $(this)[options.heightMethod]();
                    if( height > highest ){
                        highest = height;
                    }
                } );

                // Set that height on the element
                $this.css( options.setHeightOn, highest );
            } else {
                // Add check so this doesn't have to happen everytime
                $this.css( options.setHeightOn, 0 );
            }
        };

        // Call once to set initially
        if (options.delay){
            setTimeout(resizeHeight, options.delayCount); 
        } else {
            resizeHeight();
        }

        // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default.
        $(window).resize(resizeHeight);
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Code pen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbzKs

Comment: Please don't abuse `rel` like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an automatic script, you need to do a recursive function like that :

```
var $all = $('.equalHeight'),
    arrEqualH = [];

recursiveFilter()

function recursiveFilter(){
    var attr = $all.first().attr('rel');
    arrEqualH.push($('[rel='+attr+']'));
    $all = $all.not('[rel='+attr+']');

    if($all.length) recursiveFilter()
}

$.each(arrEqualH, function(){
    this.equalHeightColumns();
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2w9tq/

Answer (score 0):

You could try that:

```
$(".row").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".equalHeight[rel='group1']").equalHeightColumns();
    $(this).find(".equalHeight[rel='group2']").equalHeightColumns();
});
```

Comment: Psst.. you need to double check your quoting :)

Comment: No I definitely dont want to manually declare them, plus I need to remove the row.